# I Want To Create Quadtree

Tags: c#, quadtree

I want to create a Quad tree but it doesn't work correctly. I get a rectangle and then divide it until width and height is greater than 1 . But it doesn't divide correctly. Can you help me?
Thanks.
Here is my code.

```
public class QuadTree
{
    public TreeNode MainRoot;            
    bool Switch=false;                         

    public QuadTree(Rectangle R)          
    {
        MainRoot = new TreeNode();
        MainRoot.Rectangle = R;
        MainRoot.LeftChild = null;
        MainRoot.RightChild = null;
    }

    public void CreateTree(TreeNode Root, Rectangle R)
    {
        if (Root.Rectangle.Width<=1 || Root.Rectangle.Height <=1)
        {
            return;
        }
        Root.LeftChild = new TreeNode();
        Root.RightChild = new TreeNode();
        if (!Switch)
        {
            Root.LeftChild.Rectangle = new Rectangle(R.X, R.Y, R.Width / 2, R.Height);
            Root.RightChild.Rectangle = new Rectangle(R.X + R.Width / 2, R.Y, R.Width/2, R.Height);
        }

        if (Switch)
        {
            Root.LeftChild.Rectangle = new Rectangle(R.X, R.Y, R.Width, R.Height / 2);
            Root.RightChild.Rectangle = new Rectangle(R.X, R.Y - R.Height / 2, R.Width, R.Height / 2);
        }

        Switch = !Switch;
        CreateTree(Root.LeftChild, Root.LeftChild.Rectangle);
        CreateTree(Root.RightChild, Root.RightChild.Rectangle);
    }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean 'divide true'?

Comment: is that for fun or you needed to work with? [C# QuadTree](http://csharpquadtree.codeplex.com/) project in Code Plex does exactly that...

Comment: for example I have a rectangle 10*10 and I want divide it and finally I want 100 rectangle 1*1 ... but my code doesn't work.

Comment: Why `R.Y - R.Height / 2` and not `R.Y + R.Height / 2`?

Comment: Also, you should probably pass a parameter switch into the recursive calls instead of manipulating a field.

Comment: Yes , I should pass switch such as parameter . thank you

Comment: but R.Y - R.Height / 2 is true because in C# starter point in rectangle is top-left